# Why does `w` here require more system calls than a simple python script?

Tags: debugging, strace

I would like to dive deep into under **Linux** more and have been playing with a nice tool [`strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) (**Version: 4.11**) on **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and I am curious as to why call like the following

```
# strace -c w
```

requires higher number of system calls than say, a simple **python** script which might print a string 10 times?

In order to be more specific here is the output of `strace -c w`

```
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
shan     tty7     :0               13:20    3:37m  8:14   0.72s /sbin/upstart --user
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 61.67    0.000037           0       487         4 open
 23.33    0.000014           0       478           read
 15.00    0.000009           0       485           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           write
  0.00    0.000000           0       226           stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        38           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        27           lseek
  0.00    0.000000           0        63           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        31           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0        14           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         5           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0        22           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0        19        19 access
  0.00    0.000000           0        30           alarm
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           socket
  0.00    0.000000           0         2         2 connect
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           uname
  0.00    0.000000           0        20           fcntl
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           getdents
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0         2         2 statfs
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           futex
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000060                  1965        27 total
```

For `strace -c /tmp/loop.py`

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000160           9        18           getdents
  0.00    0.000000           0        54           read
  0.00    0.000000           0        10           write
  0.00    0.000000           0        44         2 open
  0.00    0.000000           0        45           close
  0.00    0.000000           0       108        16 stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        69           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        10           lstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        30         6 lseek
  0.00    0.000000           0        32           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        16           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        14           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0        68           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0        13         1 ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         9         9 access
  0.00    0.000000           0        10           select
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           dup
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           fcntl
  0.00    0.000000           0         4         2 readlink
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           sysinfo
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getuid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getgid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           geteuid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getegid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           sigaltstack
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           futex
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrandom
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000160                   573        36 total
```

### Inference

- `w` requires 1965 calls in total as compared to `576` calls from the python script.

### Question

- Is this implementation specific? i.e. Had I written a code in C/C++ rather than python would the `read` calls be more?
- do calls increase with increasing complexity of the program or tool used? Is there any correlation?
- Why are there more errors in executing the script as compared to `w`?

#### Note

- the python script here is a simple loop which prints **Check** as a string 10 times and has no level of complexity in it. (Code not included for *brewity*)

Comment: Well, to understand why they make all those syscalls, you need to run `strace` w/o the `-c`—then for example you'd see `w` scanning through `/proc`. You probably will have to refer to the C source code to really understand what's going on though. You're more or less trying to understand an essay by counting the number of times each individual word occurs, and asking us what it means that one essay has more *the*'s than another.

Comment: I see. I tried it with `-v` flag and I realized what you are mentioning.

Comment: How many system calls are there when you reimplement `w` in Python?

Answer (score 3):

System calls are independent of language; one can easily write a tool in assembly that is *slower* than an equivalent implementation in a high level language if one makes inefficient use of system calls; a highly contrived yet simple example to illustrate this point would be:

```
$ strace -c perl -e 'print "A"x9999' >/dev/null
...
100.00    0.000026                   224        23 total
$ strace -c ./max >/dev/null
...
100.00    0.000430                 10000           total
```

Where `./max` is the following IA-64 assembly program for Linux:

```
SECTION .text
Message: db "A"
global _start
_start:
mov r9,9999
_again:
        mov rax,1       ; sys_write
        mov rdi,1       ; stdout
        mov rsi,Message
        mov rdx,1
        syscall
        dec r9
        jnz _again
_finish:
        mov rax,60      ; sys_exit
        mov rdi,0       ; exit code
        syscall
```

As compiled via

```
$ nasm -f elf64 -o max.o max.asm ; ld -o max max.o
```

The programs *must* perform the same task for a direct comparison to be valid.

Calls probably generally increase with the complexity of the tool used, though one can contrive a contradictory case of a fantastically complicated neural network that only makes use of `sys_read` (to obtain input) `sys_write` (to emit output) and then maybe `sys_exit`. I guess you could analyze the number of system calls versus "complexity" (maybe lines of code?) and plot that up to see if there are any trends? (Reading up on "unikernel" might be informative with regard to complexity wrangling.)

The error column is how many errors there are, as shown by closing standard output and then calling something that writes to that and then obviously fails:

```
$ strace -c ./max >&-
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000427           0      9999      9999 write
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000427                 10000      9999 total
```